# React native: Keep having this error after running the command 'react-native run-android'

Tags: react-native

error: Error: Unable to resolve module @react-navigation/core from C:\Users\User\Lec5WebServer\node_modules@react-navigation\native\lib\module\createAppContainer.js: @react-navigation/core could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules
..\node_modules

Anyone know what the problem exactly is? I can't run any project now.

Comment: Are you using Yarn? If not install yarn and build with yarn

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that you have installed @react-navigation/core?
If yes, try this:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`
2. Delete node_modules: `rm -rf node_modules` and run `yarn install`
3. Reset Metro's cache: `yarn start --reset-cache`
4. Remove the cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-*`

Instead of `yarn` you can use `npm install` and `npm run` also.

Comment: I'm having this issue: 'watchman' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. What is watchman actually and how to solve this?